# NET 7 C# Controller test does not return Success Code when ForEach loop is included in MediatR RequestHandler class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, webassembly

In my wasm c# application, I'm trying to test my `ContactController`. In the `ContactControllerTests` class, I have a test named `ReturnsSuccessResult()`.  However, when I run a test for `ReturnsSuccessResult()`, the test crashes with an error 500 (Internal Server Error).

I'm using a view model class, `ContactListVm`, a query class, `GetContactListquery.cs`, and a query handler, `GetContactListQueryHandler.cs`.

You will see in the `GetContactListQueryHandler.cs` that a loop is getting and mapping a state ID and state abbreviation to the view model.  I think this causes the error because, if I remove the loop then controller unit test is successful.

Can you tell me what I'm missing or doing incorrectly when testing the `ContactController`?

**ContactListVm**

```cs
public class ContactListVm
{
  public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public string LastName { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public string NameSuffix {get; set;} = string. Empty;
  public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
  public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
  public string? Title { get; set; }
  public string Address1 { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public string? Address2 { get; set; }
  public string? Address3 { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public Guid StateId { get; set; }
  public string? StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
  public string ZipCode { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public string? Email { get; set; }
  public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string. Empty;
  public string? Fax { get; set; }
}
```

**GetContactListQuery**

```cs
public class GetContactListQuery : IRequest<List<ContactListVm>>
{
    
}
```

**GetContactListQueryHandler**

```cs
public GetContactListQueryHandler(IMapper mapper, IContactRepository contactRepository,
        IStateRepository stateRepository)
{
        _mapper = mapper;
        _contactRepository = contactRepository;
        _stateRepository = stateRepository;
}
public async Task<List<ContactListVm>> Handle(GetContactListQuery request, CancellationToken 
        cancellationToken)
{
        var allContacts = (await _contactRepository.ListAllAsync())
            .OrderBy(c => c.LastName);

        var newContactList = new List<ContactListVm>();

        foreach (var contact in allContacts)  // Error goes away if refactored to remove this foreach
        {
            var contactDetailDto = _mapper.Map<ContactListVm>(contact);
            if (contactDetailDto.StateId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var state = await _stateRepository.GetByIdAsync(contactDetailDto.StateId);
                contactDetailDto = _mapper.Map(state, contactDetailDto);
            }
            newContactList.Add(contactDetailDto);
        }

  return newContactList;
}
```

**Contact Controller**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly IMediator _mediator;

public ContactController(IMediator mediator)
{
  _mediator = mediator;
}

[HttpGet("all", Name ="GetAllContacts")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<ContactListVm>>> GetAllContacts()
{
   var dtos = await _mediator.Send(new GetContactListQuery());
   return Ok(dtos);
}

[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetContactById")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ContactDetailVm>> GetContactById(Guid id)
{
    var getContactDetailQuery = new GetContactDetailQuery() { Id = id };
    return Ok(await _mediator.Send(getContactDetailQuery));
}

[HttpPost(Name = "AddContact")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CreateContactCommandResponse>> Create
            ([FromBody] CreateContactCommandResponse createContactCommand)
{
            var response = await _mediator.Send(createContactCommand);
            return Ok(response);
}
}

**Contact Controller Tests**

[Collection("Controllers Test Collection")]
public class ContactControllerTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
 private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
 private readonly Mock<IMediator> _mediatorMock;
 private readonly ContactController _contactController;
    
 public ContactControllerTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
    _mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
    _contactController = new ContactController(_mediatorMock.Object);
}
    
[Fact]
public async Task ReturnsSuccessResult()    //<-- 500 Internal Server Error in this test
{
            var client = _factory.GetAnonymousClient();
    
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/contact/all");
    
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ContactListVm>>(responseString);
    
            Assert.IsType<List<ContactListVm>>(result);
            Assert.NotEmpty(result);
}
```

**GetContactListQueryHandlerTests**

```
    public class GetContactListQueryHandlerTests
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly Mock<IContactRepository> _mockContactRepository;
    private readonly Mock<IStateRepository> _mockStateRepository;

    public GetContactListQueryHandlerTests()
    {
        var contactRepositoryMock = new ContactRepositoryMock();
        _mockContactRepository = contactRepositoryMock.GetContactRepositoryMock();

        var stateRepositoryMock = new StateRepositoryMock();
        _mockStateRepository = stateRepositoryMock.GetStateRepositoryMock();

        var configurationProvider = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<ContactMappingProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<StateMappingProfile>();
        });
        _mapper = configurationProvider.CreateMapper();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetContactList_Result_IsOfTypeListContactListVm()
    {
        var handler = new GetContactListQueryHandler(_mapper,
            _mockContactRepository.Object, _mockStateRepository.Object);

        var result = await handler.Handle(new GetContactListQuery(),
            CancellationToken.None);

        result.ShouldBeOfType<List<ContactListVm>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at the top of your QueryHandler and stepped through it to see the exact exception being thrown? Or remove your call to `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` to see what the `responseString` says.

Comment: I sat a breakpoint at "var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/contact/all");".  It dies there and never gets to "var responseString..."

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint on the first line of that API method in your controller? Is that hit? I guess it must be since you said if you refactor your query handler the test passes, so step through the query handler and see what the exception is.

Comment: I sat a breakpoint at "var allContacts = (await _contactRepository.ListAllAsync())
            .OrderBy(c => c.LastName);" in the query handler when running the controller test and it died there.  However, using the same breakpoint, I ran the GetContactListQueryHandlerTests with the following code and it did not die.  The code for the query handler tests has been added to the original code post.

Comment: I’m not familiar with this repository patter but what if you put your OrderBy before ListAllAsync? If you wanna put this code in a repo, and nobody else answers before then, I can take a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: The OrderBy cannot be put before ListAllAsync.  I get error "Cannot resolve symbol OrderBy".   If I remove the OrderBy(...), the Internal Server Error still happens.  I could put this posted code on a Git repo, but I cannot share the entire app.

Comment: Understood, maybe someone else will be able to help you better. Are you using EntityFramework? The bug may be coming from within your `IContactRepository`.

Comment: Yes, I am using EntityFramework, and I believe that I have discovered the problem.  I will answer my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back-and-forth discussion with DSN, led me to look closely at the ReturnsSuccessResult() in the ContactControllerTests class.  That class inherits from ICLassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>.  The ReturnsSuccessResult() method populates var client = _factory.GetAnonymousClient();  The _factory.GetAnonymousClient() method is defined within the CustomWebApplicationFactory class which, in turn, uses EntityFramework to access the dbContext.

Therefore, the ContactController ReturnsSuccessResult() method uses the actual SQL Server database rather than the mocked database which is used by the integration unit tests.

On a hunch that the problem was actually due to the database, I deleted the database via the SQL Object Explorer, deleted the Migrations folder in the Persistence project of my application and then regenerated the database.

After that, the ContactControllerTests ReturnsSuccessResult() method ran successfully.  Something was out of sync, but I am not sure exactly what.

Thanks to DSN.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. If you're using EFSQL I might recommend you try out the InMemoryDatabase which allows you to interact with an actual database and not have to mock your repository layer. In my team we actually don't abstract the repository layer to a service and communicate with the database directly in the CQRS layer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after reading these two articles at learn.microsoft.com, I think I will stick with the repository pattern for testing:

[Choosing a testing strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy)
and
[Testing without the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#repository-pattern)